# Check MI for Python

Tags: python

Is there an application similar to Java's CheckMI for Python?

Comment: You might want to describe CheckMI, so we pythonistas can answer you… I went to the CheckMI site, and it sounded a bit like media-speak.

Comment: That's a tool of checking the code quality, same with the checkstyle. The meaning of MI is maintainability index what used to check the things like the comments lines whether are enough for specific source code.

Comment: Try pylint, which is a style checker for python...

Comment: Tell us specifically what code-checking capabilities it needs, e.g. does pylint fit the bill?

Answer (score 1):

Python code checkers include [PyFlakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes), [PyLint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint), [PyChecker](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyChecker), and [others](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=code+checker&submit=search).